# UI-Bootstrap Typeahead on a Modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I wanted to place a Typeahead directive on a Modal dialog. The problem is that when typeahead show it's list of possible matches it is behind modal-footer div. I played with append-to-body then the whole list is behind the modal dialog. Also played with append-to no luck. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post your code or make a plunkr with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add this attribute to html:

```
typeahead-append-to-body="true"
```

and in the css file this:

```
 .dropdown-menu {
       z-index:9999;
   }
```

Now the Typeahead displays correctly over the modal dialog.